# Aggregating a MongoDB array only returning multiple element arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, foreign-keys, aggregation-framework

I designed two mongoDB collections, one called accounts and the other called emails. I am trying to get the email address from 'accounts' in 'emails', for Sender, and Sent_To.

**accounts:**

```
{"_id":"5dc1d4b273adfdeff818d2d0","email_Addr":"aaa@example.com"},
{"_id":"5dc335d8c2169ee670b8a80b","email_Addr":"zzz.zzz@example.com"},
{"_id":"5dc33492c2169ee670b8a80a","email_Addr":"ccc@example.com"},
{"_id":"5dc335d8c2169ee670b8a80e","email_Addr":"xxx@example.com"},
{"_id":"5dcac904fe0dcf9fc0183ee2","email_Addr":"www.www@example.com"}
```

**emails:**

```
{"_id":"5dcacb41fe0dcf9fc0183ee3","Sender":"5dc1d4b273adfdeff818d2d0","Subject":"[HR-888] Notice of official announcement","Sent_To":[{"receiver":"5dc335d8c2169ee670b8a80b"}]},
{"_id":"5dcacd6efe0dcf9fc0183ee4","Sender":"5dc33492c2169ee670b8a80a","Subject":"Happy New Year! Greetings for the New Year.","Sent_To":[{"Receiver":"5dc335d8c2169ee670b8a80e"},{"Receiver":"5dcac904fe0dcf9fc0183ee2"}]}
```

Using the following aggregate I managed to have it working for Sender, but when aggregating for Sent_To it only returns if there are more than one element in the array.

```
 db.emails.aggregate([ 
 { 
    $lookup: 
    { 
        from: "accounts", 
        localField: "Sender", 
        foreignField: "_id", 
        as: "SenderId" 
    } 
 }, 
 { 
    $unwind: "$SenderId"
 }, 
 { $lookup:
   { 
        from: "accounts", 
        localField: "Sent_To.Receiver", 
        foreignField: "_id", 
        as: "SentID" 
    } 
}, 
{ 
    $project:{ 
        _id: 1, 
        Sender: "$SenderId.email_Addr", 
        Subject: 1,  
        Sent_To: "$SentID.email_Addr", 
    } 
} 
]);
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dcacb41fe0dcf9fc0183ee3"), "Subject" : "[HR-888] Notice of official announcement", "Sender" : "aaa@example.com", "Sent_To" : [ ] } //Should be Sent_To [ "zzzz.zzz@example.com" ]
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dcacd6efe0dcf9fc0183ee4"), "Subject" : "Happy New Year! Greetings for the New Year.", "Sender" : "ccc@example.com", "Sent_To" : [ "xxx@example.com", "www.www@example.com" ] }
```

Comment: Could you provide the details of the collection `emails` and `accounts`

Comment: I have just edited my question to include the original collection of emails and accounts as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple pilot error.   MongoDB is **case sensitive** with field names.  Change `receiver` to `Receiver`:

```
{"_id":"5dcacb41fe0dcf9fc0183ee3","Sen ... t_To":[{"receiver":"5dc335d8c2169ee670b8a80b"}]}
```

to

```
{"_id":"5dcacb41fe0dcf9fc0183ee3","Sen ... t_To":[{"Receiver":"5dc335d8c2169ee670b8a80b"}]}
```

Comment: @DallanByrne  DOn't forget to upvote in addition to checking as prefered answer; thanks.